# What $i-1$ means in a summation formula?

Tags: summation

What $i-1$ means when comes on the top of $∑$?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{i-1}v_i
$$

<sub>(Encountered [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdOLF.png))</sub>

If *v* is: $2, 4, 6$, then the sum will be: $2+4+6-2$?

Thanks.

Comment: that should be a typo

Comment: That's probably a typo

Comment: The expression makes no sense, since the upper bound must be independent of the running variable $i$. So, as already mentioned , this can only be a typo.

Comment: Thank you all. This expression also sounds strange to me. But it's published in a scientific paper... that is pretty confusing. I will contact the author. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no meaning. It is a typo.